# Why PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions doesn't return all assets?

Tags: ios, photosframework

There are 75 photos in My Photo Stream and 1 photo in Camera Roll(not in My Photo Stream). So totally I have 76 photos. But follow code only returns 51 photos:

```
    PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
    options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];
    assetsFetchResults = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:options];
```

I know:

> If this method is called by an app linked on or after iOS 8.1, the
>   results do not include photos synchronized to the device from iTunes
>   or photos stored in an iCloud Shared Photo Stream.

But none of the photos above are from iCloud Shared Photo Stream.

Comment: try this - [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:options];

Comment: Did you tried moments collections?

Comment: @UttamSinha no, I don't want moments.

Answer (score 4):

Not the most beautiful, but try the following to get all assets:

```
  NSMutableArray *_assets = [NSMutableArray new];

  PHFetchResult *fr = [PHAssetCollection fetchMomentsWithOptions:nil];
  for (PHAssetCollection *collection in fr) {

     PHFetchResult *_fr = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:nil];
     for (PHAsset *asset in _fr) {

        [_assets addObject:asset];
     }
  }
```